# Using Oracle ref cursor in Java without Oracle dependency

Tags: java, oracle

According to google and some other sources (e.g., http://www.enterprisedt.com/publications/oracle/result_set.html), if I want to call a stored-function that returns a ref cursor, I need to write something like this in order to access the ResultSet:

```
String query = "begin ? := sp_get_stocks(?); end;";
CallableStatement stmt = conn.prepareCall(query);
// register the type of the out param - an Oracle specific type
stmt.registerOutParameter(1, OracleTypes.CURSOR);
// set the in param
stmt.setFloat(2, price);
// execute and retrieve the result set
stmt.execute();
ResultSet rs = (ResultSet)stmt.getObject(1);
```

Is there anyway to do it without introducing the compile-time dependency on Oracle. Is there a generic alternative to OracleTypes.CURSOR?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Constant `OracleTypes.CURSOR` is -10. Quite ugly solution but you can just write -10 there or create your own constant which value is -10.

Comment: I agree it is ugly, but I didn't find anything better than this for now

Comment: This is just too ugly! Would havee been ok if it was a college project, but for any real projects, I beg you not to use this! :)

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried `java.sql.Types.OTHER`? It might work. API says, it's for database specific types.

Comment: unfortunately it doesn't work. The CallableStatement object throws an ora-17004 exception when trying to register the out parameters with Types.OTHER.